# Multiple Pagination Instance Support Fix for Custom Pagination Method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination

Hello Laravel Developers,

I have been using the following Pagination Helper to modify the built-in pagination method, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with Multiple Pagination Instance in a Single Page (2 paginations in 1 page).

```
public static function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $path = '', $pageName = 'page')
    {
        $options = [
            'path' => $path
        ];
        $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
        return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
    }
```

edit: passed the $pageName parameter, still it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $path = '', $key = '')
{
$options = [
'path' => $path,
'pageName' => $key . '_page'
];
$page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($key . '_page');
return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage),   $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}
```

try this

Comment: I find it much similar to the edits. I have tried both and it didnt work.